# Tomcat compression feature is not improving the data transfer time, though client(browser) gets content type as gzip

Tags: java, tomcat, compression

Using the data compression feature of tomcat, i am seeing that the data (json result) is compressed but the time taken for fetching data from server to client has NOT improved.

Client:borwser

Server - embedded tomcat.

Spring MVC framework with REST api's are used to serve all the client requests.
Jackson is used to convert java objects to json format.

eg:- 
**Without compression feature**
     json result size =18 MB, time taken to fetch data from server to client was 14 sec's

**Chrom developer tool info when Compression is NOT used->**

**Request Headersview source**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic dWlhZG1pbjpyZWRzZWFs
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8443
Referer:https://localhost:8443/apps.jsp
```

**Response Headers**

```
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 25 Sep 2013 10:40:59 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

**With compression feature:**
     json result size =433 KB , BUT TIME taken to fetch data from server to client was still around 14 sec's

**Chrom developer tool info when Compression is enabled ->**

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic dWlhZG1pbjpyZWRzZWFs
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8443
Referer:https://localhost:8443/apps.jsp
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Response Headers**

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 25 Sep 2013 10:16:02 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Embedded Tomcat code for the config:

```
httpsConnector.setAttribute("compression","on");
 httpsConnector.setAttribute("compressionMinSize","2048");
 httpsConnector.setAttribute("noCompressionUserAgents","gozilla, traviata");
 httpsConnector.setAttribute("compressableMimeType","application/json,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css");
```

The "transfer-encoding" has value as "chunked" in the response header, does this have any effect for my issue.
I am not able to figure out why the time to fetch data is not improved when data is compressed.
Please let me know if i am missing some configuration.

Comment: It's possible the time to compress the response has negated the time saved to download. If you use chrome you can hit F12 and use the network tab to see exactly where the time is being spent. If you post a screenshot we can take a better look.

Comment: I was not able to post a screenshot with my query. i used chrome F12 feature to check the timings, the timinigs i have mentioned in my query is purely the time taken to fetch the data, it does NOT include server processing time